# Creating throttling function with Bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I am attempting to created a throttling function. I have looked at a few SO posts and copied some code but I am unable to get it to delay.

Basically I have a number of methods in a class that need to call the Amazon API. They all make use of a common function - `doCall` which I implemented as follows:

```
Amazon.prototype.doCall = function(func) {
  var self = this;

  var queue = P.resolve();

  function throttle(fn) {
    var res = queue.then(function() { // wait for queue
      return fn(); // call the function
    });

    queue = P.delay(61000).return(queue); // make the queue wait for 61 seconds
    return res; // return the result
  }


  // Create instance of MWS client
  if (!this.client) {
    this.client = new mws.Client(key, secret, merchant, {});
  }

  var call = function() {

    // The library uses a weird signature so I am wrapping it thus
    return new P(function(resolve, reject) {

      // The original MWS library call
      self.client.invoke(func, function(r, e) {
        // ... stuff
        resolve(r);
      });
    });

  };
  return throttle(call);
};
```

Basically I fetch order lists and orders and need to delay each call 60+ seconds. Right now it all happens without a delay whatsoever. Suggestions?

I am basically using it like this (contrived but should give the idea)

```
self.doCall(ListOrders).then(function(res) { 
  // parse results
  self.doCall(ListMoreOrdersByPage).then(function(res) {
     // Now I might go through each and fetch details
     var ids = [...] // Parse result for ids
     return P.map(ids, function(id) {
       return doCall(GetOrderById);
     });  
     ....
```

Comment: Does one call need to be 60 seconds after another call ends, or 60 seconds after it starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that

> ```
> Amazon.prototype.doCall = function(func) {
>     var queue = P.resolve();
>     …
> ```

means that you are re-creating a new `queue` on every call of that method. Not really helpful. Instead you probably want one queue per `Amazon` instead, so put the initialisation in the constructor.

I've also simplified your code a bit:

```
function Amazon(…) {
  …
  this.queue = P.resolve();
}

Amazon.prototype.doCall = function(func) {
  if (!this.client) {
    // Create instance of MWS client
    this.client = new mws.Client(key, secret, merchant, {});
  }

  var self = this;
  var res = this.queue.then(function() {
    // The library uses a weird signature so I am wrapping it thus
    return new P(function(resolve, reject) {
      self.client.invoke(func, function(r, e) {
        // ... stuff
        resolve(r);
      });
    });
  });

  this.queue = this.queue.delay(610000); // make the queue wait for 61s
  // if you want to make it wait *between* calls, use
  // this.queue = res.catch(function(){}).delay(610000);
  return res;
};
```

Comment: This works well for most call but I have one method which uses `Promise.map()` - all the promises mapped get called at once.

Comment: @Yashua: In your example snippet, the call inside `P.map` doesn't use `self.doCall` for some reason?

Comment: my bad - my debug statements were throwing me off.  it's throttling ok though Amazon is still giving me throttling errors but not sure why yet. Unrelated to this code though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to come back after I had created an actual, working solution. The trick that messed me up was that you need to pass the uninvoked function into the queuer. I know this isn't what the OP was asking for, but I'm hoping this might help anyone else who comes along looking for an extensible solution.

You can see it in action here: http://jsbin.com/seqeqecate/5/

```
function asyncFunction(){
  var deferred = Promise.defer();

  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('ping');
    deferred.resolve();  
  },3000);

  return deferred.promise;
}

function AsyncQueuer(){
  var queue = [],
      running = false;

  function runQueue(){
    var first = queue.shift();

    running = true;

    if (first) {
      first.promisable.apply(first.context).then(function() {
        first.deferral.resolve();
        runQueue();
      }, 
      function() {
        first.deferral.reject();
        runQueue();
      });
    } else {
      running = false;
    }
  }

  return {
    add: function(promisable, context) {
      var deferred = Promise.defer();

      queue.push({
        promisable: promisable,
        deferral: deferred,
        context: context || window
      });

      if (!running) {
        runQueue();
      }

      return deferred;
    }
  };
}

var asyncQueuer = new AsyncQueuer();

asyncQueuer.add(asyncFunction);
asyncQueuer.add(asyncFunction);
asyncQueuer.add(asyncFunction).then(function(){}).fail(function(){});
```

Comment: His solution is convoluted and unextensible. He should use this instead. His API doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Normally I would have downvoted an answer that doesn't answer a person's question *directly*, but the direction the OP was going completely defeats the purpose of having Promises in the first place to begin with.  This answer is a lot cleaner.

Comment: I've attempted to reduce the code to the bare minimum so it may appear weird. But the MWS library is in general a total mess to work with.

Comment: I appreciate that irysius, and I'm sorry Yashua if I offended. The thing is, as irysius said, your approach was negating the point of promises to begin with.

My solution's not perfect. Ideally `.add` would, itself, return a promise that you could perhaps operate on. I'm working on it.

Comment: Added functionality to let a user gain external promise fulfillment from queued promises.

Comment: This function does neither work (it runs all three ajax requests in parallel), nor is the `AsyncQueuer` good promise code, nor does this answer the OP's question.